# About Facebook Audience network native ads template height

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network, facebook-ads

Will we get paid more if we choose to display a native ad with a higher height (i.e 400) or are all native ads the same and height doesn’t play a factor in how much ecpm you’ll get. If so what would be the point of displaying the bigger native ad when you can show one with small height.

Here’s all the heights for native ads templates:

- GenericHeight100
- GenericHeight120
- GenericHeight300
- GenericHeight400

Is it valuable to display a native ad with 400 than then one with 100? Will it increase earnings?